# Angularjs routing on an express 4.0 backend API

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I have started an application where I use Express 4.0 server. I have set up the routes based heavily on a tutorial on scotch.io (http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4), builiding a backend api to serve the front end SPA (angularjs). Here is an extract of the backend router:

```
router.route('/users')
   .get(function (req, res) {
       User.find(function(err, users) {
          if (err) {
             res.send(err);
          }
          else {
             res.json(users);
          }
       });
   })
```

Further down

```
// home page route (http://localhost:8080)
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.send('API ROOT');    
});

app.use('/api', router);
```

From the frontend i use just a get to get the users from the api:

```
$http.get('/api/users')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.users = data;
});
```

and the angular routes are set up like this:

```
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
    controller: 'MainController'
})

.when('/users', {
    templateUrl: 'views/user.html',
    controller: 'UserController'
})
```

The index.html has a link to /users.

When starting the server and goint into localhost:8080 it loads fine, and clicking the users loads the user.html view and lists the users.

However, if i click refresh when browser is in localhost:8080/users

I get:

```
Cannot get /users
```

Is it a controller issue?
Or is it a problem with backend routing?

Any feedback/suggestions would be very welcome!

Searching some more, I see that there are several sollutions that might fix this:
Either on the frontend (angular routes part) adding this to the end:

```
// >>> redirect other routes to
otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});
```

Or on the backend (after all your routes):

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.html');
});
```

Which sollution is better (or is it reccomended to use both...?)

Comment: This actually is open issue. Try [this](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/433#issuecomment-28554867)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use both.

You need to provide a catch-all / wildcard route to your express application such that any routes that are not explicitly matched will return the index page which will load Angular and allow your Angular routes to then take over. Note that this should always be your last route (they are parsed in order).

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.html');
});
```

Then in your Angular app you should have a default route to catch any un-matched routes on the client side. This route will come into effect if the application is already loaded but an unknown route is encountered whereas the server side solution above will handle any direct requests.

```
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);
```

Comment: Thanks. When it comes to Express routes in 4.0, you can have several instances of Router(). Some followup questions from me would be 1) Is it recommended to modularize your routing like this (on instance for users, one for some other stuff, one for authorization and so on) or is it better to just add everything in the same router instance? 2) If you go for several instances, do you then have to add the catchall route in the end of each router instance or just the last one? 3) is this the way to use sseveral routes: `app.use('/api', router); app.use('/', otherRouter);` and so on?

Comment: 1. Generally it is a good idea to separate your routing into modules and export the router instances. 2. You only need one catchall route, it should come after you have required your other route modules in whatever file appropriate. 3. if you are wanting to mount `router` under the `/api` path yes, the second case you could just use `app.use(otherRouter)`

Comment: I don't use both. I do one catchall in my angular app.js (otherwise) - and that takes case of all routes that are not handled.
Not sure i what case you need more than that ?

Comment: Angular routes only take control once your Angular app has been bootstrapped. Before that you are relying on your server to serve up the index page with the Angular scripts attached. What happens if your server receives a request that is not explicitly for the index page? You will still need to serve the index page and then allow the Angular routing to display the appropriate view. That is why you also need a wildcard route server side.